# Computation time of a bash script scales horribly

Tags: bash, math

I have the following code that is addressing the Project Euler problem below:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

My script works fine, generates me 2520 as it should do for 1-10, I also have an answer for 1-17 of 12252240, it looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<10000000000; i++))
 do
if (( i%2 == 0 )) && (( i%3 == 0 )) && (( i%4 == 0 )) && (( i%5 == 0 )) &&
   (( i%6 == 0 )) && (( i%7 == 0 )) && (( i%8 == 0 )) && (( i%9 == 0 )) && 
   (( i%10 == 0 )) && (( i%11 == 0 )) && (( i%12 == 0 )) && (( i%13 == 0 )) &&
   (( i%14 == 0 )) && (( i%15 == 0 )) && (( i%16 == 0 )) && (( i%17 == 0 )); then 
    # remaning terms to factor && (( i%18 == 0 )) && (( i%19 == 0 )) && (( i%20 == 0 )); then 
    int=$i
fi

if [[ $int ]]; then
 echo "Lowest integer = '$int'"
 break
 else
     continue
fi


done
```

However, the jump from factoring around 12 terms (about 3/4th of a second real time), to factoring 17 (6 mins real time), in computational time is huge.

I've yet to let the full 20 factors run, but all Project Euler problems are supposed to be solvable in a few minutes on medium power home computers.

So my question is 2 fold: 1) Am I on the right track in terms of how I approached programming this, and 2) how else could/should I have done it to make it as efficient as possible?

Comment: I you want raw speed, good type checking and modern abstractions, use C++.

Comment: Hint: The solution to this problem is NOT to examine numbers until you find one that fits. Another hint: You can solve this problem with a calculator and a piece of paper in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Oh I realise the mathematics of the problem is fairly trivial, but that's kind of the point. Project Euler just gives you small tasks to try and achieve in whatever programming system takes your fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without abandoning the brute-force approach, running the inner loop in reverse order roughly halves the running time.

```
for ((i=1; i<100000000; ++i)); do
  for ((j=17; j>1; --j)); do
    (( i%j != 0 )) && break
  done
  ((j==1)) && echo "$i" && break
done
```

Informally speaking, almost no numbers are divisible by 17, and out of those, almost no numbers are divisible by 16.  Thus, running the inner loop in reverse order removes 16 iterations of the inner loop for most numbers, and 15 for most of the rest.

Additional optimizations are obvious; for example, the inner loop could end at 4, because 2, 3, and 4 are already covered by their respective squares (all numbers which are divisible by 9 are also divisible by 3, etc).  However, that's small potatoes compared to the main optimization.

(You did not have an explicit inner loop, and in fact, unrolling the loop like you did probably achieves a small performance gain.  I rolled it into an explicit loop mainly out of laziness as well as for aesthetic reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is 2 fold:
>
> 1) Am I on the right track in terms of how I approached programming this, and

I'm afraid you're not. You're using the wrong tools, namely a shell scripting language, to solve mathematical problems, and wonder why that doesn't perform well. "being solvable in a couple of minutes on a home computer" doesn't mean it's supposed to be like that, no matter how unusual your choice of tool is.

> 2) how else could/should I have done it to make it as efficient as possible?

Don't use bash's arithmetics. Bash is a shell, which means it's an interpreter to its core. Which means that it'll spend very little time calculating, and very much time understanding what it should do. To illustrate: Your complicated formula first has to be parsed into a tree that tells bash in which order to execute things, then these things have to be identified, then bash needs to work through that tree and save all the results for the next level of the tree. The few arithmetic instructions that it does cost next to no computational time.

Have a look at numpy, which is a python module for mathematics; it does things faster. If you're not afraid to compile your stuff, look at C++ or C, both for which very very fast math libraries exist.

Comment: I should add then perhaps, that I'm using Project Euler to teach myself some more bash syntax and so on. I could do it with anything and I realise this isn't what bash is 'for', but it's bash I'm trying to learn at the moment.

If there are any tricks and general good practice for making scripts in bash (or anything else for that matter) faster/cleaner/better, that's what I'm really asking here I suppose.

Comment: @JoeHealey: that doesn't change the underlying fact that when you do something syntactically complex and need performance, bash is just not the tool of choice; so no matter how well you approach this problem, you'd basically be learning the "wrong" things.

Comment: Bash is a nice tool, but I never saw it as a programming language -- whenever there is a problem that's not most efficiently solved by calling a few programs, I just write my script in python etc -- it really means nothing more than using a less shell-oriented language and changing the `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/python`; on modern machines there's little reason to build complex tools with 80's/90's shell script languages.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic conditions support logical operators. The speed gain is not huge, but there's some:

```
if (( i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0 && ... ))
```

Also note, that testing `i % 10 == 0` when you already know that `i % 2 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0` is not needed.

There's a much faster way how to get the number without iterating over all the numbers.

Comment: That had occurred to me actually, these Project Euler problems nearly always have a mathematical trick at their core that you can exploit to achieve things faster. As the code was working for the smaller ranges I didn't change it, but I'll explore that option - thanks!

Comment: To get divisibility by for example 16 you need all 4 factors of 2, so just testing primes is not sufficient. You also need the largest prime power smaller than the given limit as a factor in the result.

Comment: @LutzL: True. I edited the answer. I'm trying to answer the questions, not to solve the task, though.

Comment: Also true. But just searching here for "2520 project euler" gives tons of questions and answers, so (aggressive) hiding of hints is somewhat unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not a faster programming language.  The answer is a more clever algorithm.

You know your end answer has to be divisible by all of the numbers, so start with your largest number and only check multiples of it.  Find the smallest number that is a multiple of your two biggest numbers, and then check only multiples of that for the next number.

Let's look at how this works for 1 to 10:

```
10  // not divisible by 9, keep adding 10's until divisible by 9
20  
30  
40  
50  
60
70
80
90  // divisible by 9, move on to 8, not divisible by 8, keep adding 90's
180
270
360 // divisible by 8, not divisible by 7, keep adding 360's
720
1080
1440
1800
2160
2520  // divisible by 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 so you're done!
```

So in only 17 steps, you have your answer.

This algorithm implemented in Ruby (not known for its speed) found the answer for 1-5000 in 4.5 seconds on a moderately fast laptop.